# Drop empty string columns in astropy

Tags: python, csv, astropy

Is there an easy way to drop empty columns in astropy tables?
When reading some csv files, some columns only contain empty strings `''`.

Comment: Test if the column is all empty strings and delete it if so?

Answer (score -1):

Try looping over the length of the table 't' and then remove the rows that are empty strings like this:

```
dele = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i] == '':
        dele.append(i)
t.remove_rows(dele)
```

Comment: Some comments for improvement of this answer? (Please comment when 'down' voting)